Which is more feasible/makes more sense to implement at the discrete transistor level, NMOS logic or TTL?
I'm currently working on a discrete transistor computer project, and I'm somewhat caught between TTL and NMOS. I was originally going to implement CMOS logic, but after I made a previous post, someone much more knowledgeable than I recommended I use NMOS instead.
My project has come a long was since then. I have a simple emulator working to test programs before I have actual hardware, and I'm currently designing and experimenting with logic circuits. Although RTL is simple, the fan out is terrible, it's too slow, and it's just too fiddly at the scale I want to build. DTL is slower than TTL at a comparable cost and complexity, so I've made some simple TTL logic gates to do some testing.
However, the speed and lower power consumption of NMOS is still alluring. I've even run some simulations in LTSpice, and even after implementing gate drivers with some decent resistances, it also runs remarkably well.
This means that I have two options I can't really decide between. TTL will consume more power, but with some cleverness, it's not too much more than NMOS, but NMOS has faster switching speeds and slower propagation delay, as well as a much larger fan out, which may play a role in increasing clock speed.
As long as my computer functions, I'll be more than happy, but the goal is to support a clock speed of up to 100Khz. If that's not feasible with either, then something around a 10Khz maximum is more than enough. All of this is new to me, so I'm unsure as to what's a realistic expectation.
Given that, which would be better to use?

Aside from speed, what are your criteria.  For example, you mention fanout. Do you need fanout? - because if you don't,  you may choose not to worry about it.

As a data point, the Monster 6502 runs at about 50 kHz.

When you say "NMOS", are you referring to N-channel MOSFETs with pull-up drain resistors? And when you say "TTL" are you using the term in its strict sense, referring to dual-NPN totem-pole outputs? If so, then I would argue that NMOS is potentially an order of magnitude slower than TTL. In either case, the fanout issue alone is enough to convince me to stick with NMOS.

@ScottSeidman Fanout is more of a minor concern, as I can just implement tri-state logic on the data and address busses instead of pulling them high with resistors.

@SimonFitch You got both of them spot on, and I'll be posting some of the circuits I've been working on later to see if I need to make any changes. Fanout isn't as much of an issue, but how would NMOS be slower? Even with a gate resistor to dampen ringing, it seems to have a better switching speed in my simulations.

@DaveTweed That's a really good reference point. I plan for the computer to have a larger surface area and use slower components, but I wager I can get it to about 25Khz at the size I'm gonna build at.

Your layout and gate impedance will affect speed and power consumption.  What are your priorities? speed? cost, size, technology, assembly method, fault detection, self test ?

@ZachS 10k pull-up resistor could take anything between 100ns and 1μs to charge the next gate. TTL switches in tens of nanoseconds.

@SimonFitch Would I need to use such a high pull up resistor?

@D.A.S. My priorities are speed and layout. I intend for this to function both as a hobbyist computer and as a teaching tool. I want to build something comparable in size to Usagi Electric's vacuum tube computer with a layout style similar to the Megaprocessor. Part of my motivation to use discrete transistors is to allow people to see how every part of the computer works down to the smallest level.

@Zach You don't have to use 10k. It was just to illustrate how your speed claim is debatable. I suggest you run some tests in a simulator, a few gates in series, to see propagation delay.

Ken Shirriff's transistor-based computer.
Ben Eater's 8-bit computer for logic insights.
Historical computers like the PDP-8 for inspiration.

Zach  do you know that layout and device mismatch will affect race conditions? Do you know how to predict/prevent them?  How about a tolerance stackup?  Discrete versions of IC's will often fail to work without a clear understanding of setup and hold time requirements. to change a design to work in discrete parts..

@D.A.S. I'm aware of the effect of layout and device mismatch, it's actually one of the main reasons I moved away from CMOS (the shoot-through was ridiculous). I'm not aware of any techniques to recognize them besides seeing unexpected results in testing and adding up circuit propogatiom delays, though I plan to take that into account when selecting a clock speed, so that circuits have time to settle before they're changed again.

Shoot thru is due to  Ids = beta * (Vgs - Vt)^2/2.  for Beta = 20m , and Vgs= Vdd  , (Vdd -Vt) has a strong effect on Id, which is why all CMOS IC's require a decoupling cap. But if you limit Vdd to 2Vt the current is absorbed easily by a 10 nF cap. But the energy is controlled by Cout*Vdd^2/2 which if only 6 pF can be quite small while a higher RdsOn lowers shoot thru still has a high slew rate of RdsOn * Ctotal =Tau So by reducing Vdd, like in 74ALC family you can get high speed with low Vdd.

@D.A.S. I've kept experimenting with CMOS, and I think I've made some progress on getting fast, clean output signals. I'm using a Vdd of 5V, and the Vt on both the NMOS and PMOS I'm using is nominally ~2.5. I also added some decoupling capacitors, and they've worked wonders. I'm still getting some spikes in current, but they last for less than a quarter microsecond, topping out at a max of 30mA. What kind of current spikes would you say are safe?

That should be a measurement error unless you used the tip and ring on  a 10:1 probe.

@D.A.S. Oh, I'm still waiting on my FETs to come in, so I'm running simulations in LTSpice.

There are 3 ways to build NMOS logic.  (1) Resistive pull-up, (2) enhancement mode pull-up, and (3) depletion mode pull-up.  If I recall correctly, most of the NMOS ICs used the 3rd method since it's the most efficient.  It's hard to build with discrete parts, though, due to lack of depletion mode MOSFETs (you can try using a JFET instead).  The 2nd one is also hard to build with discrete parts since you need the pull-up MOSFET's body tied to VSS like in an IC.  The first is the most practical for discrete builds, but as everyone mentioned, it's highly dependent on the pull-up resistor value.

Here is a reference which highlights the difference between (2) and (3): http://www.ece.mcgill.ca/~grober4/SPICE/SPICE_Decks/1st_Edition/chapter13/Chapter%2013%20MOS%20Digital%20Ccts%20web%20version.html

("long was since" long way since) "and slower propagation delay" lower delay? (What is a faster speed, anyway? faster switching, or higher switching speed.)

Neither. Handmade NMOS logic requires pullup resistors, and BJT logic needs those and base resistors.
I reckon NMOS would be marginally easier of the two but... whoever steered you away from CMOS didn't do you any favors. CMOS solves problems with drive and static power consumption that bedevil older logic families, while providing more flexibility in logic design.
You can obtain reasonably-priced discrete n-FETs and p-FETs. The 2N7002 NMOS and BSS84 PMOS transistors seem to be the least expensive ones stocked at Digi-Key. If you settle on this for your aesthetic reasons, buying them in bulk is more cost-effective. And if you use SOT-23, even better: they’re less expensive.
(I looked into the Megaprocessor. Idea: you could make a single 'gate' board type and configure it with straps to model a specific gate type.)
But... may I suggest instead using CMOS FETs in the form of the CD4007. Here's what's inside:

Each CD4007 DIP package contains two uncommitted p-FETs, 2 uncommitted n-FETs, and an inverter pair. From this basic kit you can construct all the basic 2-input gate types (NAND, NOR, AND, OR) plus a lot of other cool stuff, like transmission-gate logic (e.g., for muxes and latches) that's much harder to do with other logic types.
Being 4000 series CMOS, your power will be low (next to nothing). You don't need to burn any power in resistors like you would with BJT's or NMOS.
Finally, the CD4007 DIP packaging is convenient for handmade prototyping, more so than TO-92 of a discrete device.
Even if you decide against using the CD4007, the idea of a standard, reconfigurable block based on 6 discrete FETs would be useful.

Thanks a lot for the advice. I've been experimenting in LTSpice with CMOS and TTL, and I've managed to throw together some standard gate designs that function really well. The switching speed between CMOS and TTL is also markedly different.
As for the gate board type, I initially planned to just put a bunch of gates on one board to make construction easier, like a whole ALU slice or D Flip-Flop, but now I'm planning to make some boards similar to IBM's old Standard Modular System for prototyping.

With common cheap BJTs to reach 100 kHz you have to use an Ic:Ib ratio of about 10 or 20. This is not negligible.
Of course, it is possible use speed-up capacitors, but it will increase the parts count.
At very high frequencies FETs and BJTs are the same in consumption because of the FETs' capacity that now has to be charged often.

Another thing that might help with BJTs (but also increase the part count) is using Schottky diodes as Baker clamps.

At the component level, RTL or DTL probably make more sense.
CMOS and TTL both exploit the price difference that transistors are crazy cheap in monolithic ICs
If you absolutely must use one of TTL or CMOS, then it's tricky,  BJTs are slightly cheaper but you'll need base resistors, whereas MOSFETs can probably be used without resistors.

In production I was buying 2N7002's for about the same price as 2N3904s.

In fact... found them for 1.5 cents apiece (3000 qty) at Digi-key. Link: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/venkel/2N7002K-EVL/21363662

Hmm I can get 2N7002s for 0.41c and S8050s for 0.30c at qty 3000 at LCSC so the prices are closer than I remember.

These are cheap as resistors with many sources.  https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/MOSFETs_KUU-2N7002_C2944141.html?utm_source=digipart&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=2N7002

yeah, I was mainly thinking of the hassle of installing them all.

I missed that the question was NMOS not CMOS

I think your answer still holds even if you replace CMOS with NMOS.

TTL requires so many transistors and resistors that it's not overly practical. Sure it can be done but it's IMHO more painful than making a relay-based computer.
Discrete logic is easiest to make using CMOS pairs, i.e. NMOS+PMOS pairs. Those are available in small packages. E.g. DMC2991UDJ-7B in SOT963 - it's a logic-level threshold part, with channel resistance around 1Ω. About $80 for 1000 pieces. For a reasonable 16-bit machine you'll probably need 10k pairs at least. With a 3-stage pipeline it'd be probably 30k pairs.
The input capacitance will always be less than ideal on those discrete parts. It's not terrible - about 20pF. You should be able to make a 1MHz or faster machine using those parts if you're careful.
Make sure that you automate the generation of the layout using scripting. You'll need to design the thing using e.g. KiCad, using sub-circuits (multiple-instance sheets). That can be read using a Python script that will then sprinkle the parts on a board, route them on a Manhattan grid, and dump a KiCad PCB file out.
For prototyping low-level design primitives you can do PCB layout by hand. Once you start putting a thousand parts per board, it'll lose the allure.
The design should be for a 4-layer board. The middle planes should be supply and ground. Decoupling capacitors to be sprinkled on the bottom, one per every dozen transistor pairs or so. They don't need to be large - 10nF in SMT is all you need.
Then you'll want to get this stuff machine-built - soldering these by hand, even with stencils, is IMHO not worth it. Spend the time instead making good software for the thing. Hardware is usually the easy part. Software that will run on it and necessary tooling (assembler, linker, maybe a simple C compiler) is where you'll spend 95% of the time.
Homebrew computers with custom architectures often stop short of actually being useful for anything. Look at Homebrew CPU for some idea. You may even wish to reimplement the same instruction set but using a different architecture, based on discrete CMOS. That way you could reuse all the effort that went into making the software for that one. It would then be useful - you could run Minix on it, put it on a network, and generally enjoy it much more than something that will run a simple assembly program and end there.
